# Как убрать или поменять цвет "якоря" под курсором Plain text в Android?

Tags: android, cursor, edittext

Мне надо оформить поле ввода по примеру, а там по умолчанию после введения текста, чтобы перемещать курсор есть такой якорь, на вид как капля. Хочу его убрать или хотя бы поменять его цвет. [image: уточненение что я имею ввиду]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта штука называется handles в Edittext. Убрать можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745986/disable-remove-text-select-handle-from-edittext-in-android):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >

 <size
    android:height="0dp"
    android:width="0dp" />

 </shape>
```

и добавить в поле для ввода:

```
android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/your_empty_image"
```

изменение цвета описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handles).